# Keyboard Accessibility in Web Applications

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, javascript, accessibility

I would put my question this way:
We all know Keyboard is fast (as compare to Mouse). VIM is a simplest example for this.

Is there any standard of creating web applications that are keyboard centric? There could be different "non-standard" ways e.g. using Lynx Web Browser, create JS keyboard shortcuts using JQuery, etc.

@Chris: I understand that Web Application Runs under another application (Web Browser) and this is a limitation. 
But my question is: Since WWW is expanding and is now much more than Just browsing and includes applications.  Now user need to work their full day in data entry and manipulating data, why don't we have (or do we have) any standards to make that user experience fast. 
I have seen users working on DOS based application using Keyboard like anything. They use "Enter" keys, "numeric pad" and all.

Answer (score 2):

The browsers themselves will have "standard" or reasonably standard keyboard shortcuts (backspace for navigate backwards for example), but I wouldn't expect the actual applications to have keyboard shortcuts - standard or otherwise.

Why? Because the browser gets to handle the input first, so application developers will need to pick shortcuts that don't clash with**any** browser. This will be a very small set and so there won't be any consistency from one application to the next.

Having said that, you can navigate between input fields by using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key and send forms by using <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I got you! But is not it a limitation. I have seen users for DOS based application using Keyboard like anything. They use enter keys, numeric pad and all. My question is: Can we create such a web application that emulates this great and fast user experience?

Comment: @Sandeep - yes, but you'd have to work within the limitations imposed by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The `accesskey` attribute is the W3C-defined and WCAG-/Section 501-approved method - The excellent Dive Into Accessibility has a list of [standard keyboard shortcuts](http://diveintoaccessibility.org/day_15_defining_keyboard_shortcuts.html) which should be available on most web sites.

Related question: [Keyboard shortcuts with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593602/keyboard-shortcuts-with-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the standards for the Keyboard based Web Applications, but what I find is KeyBoard Based Web Browser.

This would definitely help in fast processing of web applications. 
The one I have currently installed is [Vimperator](http://vimperator.org/)

This disables all the Web Browser's default key strokes.